# Best practices for copying large amounts of files

Tags: external-hard-drive

I got a new 2TB WD Ultra External HDD and want to transfer all files from my 3 year old external hard disk to the new one.

Does it really matter if I select all and copy and paste once, or should I select files for example to not exceed 100GB at a time to prevent failure of new hard disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't matter at all, as long as there are no defects with either drive.
The OS will copy one file at a time until it's done, it won't try to move terabytes of data instantly. It will only run at the speed of the old drive, not break it by trying to pull it all out at USB 3 speeds.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter whether you mark all files and copy or just a bunch of. Only thing you should keep care, if you have any chance, to

- Don't run high memory consuming applications during copy so your OS can use more RAM for buffering
- Don't put them at the very same USB controller: Most of PC and Laptops are having only a little number of controller using hubs to offer more ports. So even you got maybe 10 USB ports, they might be ruled by just on chip and this boy is having amaximal transfer limit, which its splitting by 2